# Find the splitting field of the following polynomials.

Tags: splitting-field

Find the splitting field $E$ of the following polynomials and the degree of the extension

> **1)** $X^4-1\in\mathbb Q[X]$

$X^4-1=(X-1)(X+1)(X^2+1)=(X+1)(X-1)(X+i)(X-i)$
therefore $E=\mathbb Q(i)\cong \mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)$
and thus $[E:\mathbb Q]=2$.

*I had 0/10 on the question, and the remark was: "the justification is not correct". Could someone explain me why ?*

> **2)** $X^7-1\in\mathbb Q[X]$

We have that $$X^7-1=(X-1)(X^6+...+1)$$
with $X^6+...+1$ irreducible.

$$X^7-1=0\iff X^7=1\iff X=e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{7}},\ k=0,...,6.$$
Therefore $$E=\mathbb Q(1,e^{\frac{2i\pi}{7}},...,e^{\frac{12i\pi}{7}})\cong\mathbb Q[X]/(x^6+...+1),$$

and thus $[E:\mathbb Q]=6$.

*Is my justification correct ?*

> **3)** $X^p-t\in\mathbb F_p(t)[X]$

$t$ is irreducible on $\mathbb F_p(t)$ therefore, by Eisenstein criterion, $X^p-t$ is irreducible over $F_p(t)[X]$.

*I have to describe $E$, but how can I solve $X^p=t$ on $\mathbb F_p(t)$ ? I would say that $$X^p=t\iff X=e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{p}}\sqrt[p]t, k=0,...,p-1$$
but the $e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{p}}\sqrt[p]t\notin\mathbb F_p(t)$, therefore I don't know how to do.*

> **4)** The minimal polynomials of $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$

The minimal polynomial is given by $X^4-10X^2+1$. The roots of this polynomials are
$$\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3,\quad -\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3,\quad \sqrt 2-\sqrt 3\quad\text{and}\quad \sqrt 3-\sqrt 2.$$
We have that $$E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3,-\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3,-\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3,\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3).$$

But $$-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt 3=-(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)\in\mathbb Q(sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$$
$$\sqrt 2-\sqrt 3=\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3}\in\mathbb Q(sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$$
$$-\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3}\in\mathbb Q(sqrt 2+\sqrt 3),$$

therefore $$E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)\cong\mathbb Q[X]/(X^4-10X+1)$$
and thus $[E:\mathbb Q]=4$.

*is it correct ?*

Comment: On #4, how do you know that $x^4-10x^2+1$ is irreducible?

Comment: It has been proved in a previous exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): perhaps the lecturer (or whoever marked your exam) wanted some explanation: why does $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$ is the splitting field of $\;x^4-1\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ ? Does it contain all the roots of the polynomial? Is this the minimal such field? You only wrote "therefore..." .

For (2): what did you need for the first part? The real thing, imo, is

$$\;x^7=1\iff x=e^{2\pi k i/7}\;,\;\;k=0,1,...,6\;$$

I'd expect though that you'll write, with perhaps a little explanation, that

$$e^{2\pi ki/t}=\left(e^{2\pi i/7}\right)^k\implies E=\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/7})$$

Also, **why** do you say $\;x^6+x^5+\ldots+x+1\;$ is irreducible (over the rationals)? Did you propose a proof for this, or at least mentioned something that could justify this?

For (3): your use of Eisenstein is correct, *though* it could probably be better to connect it to the "natural" integral domain $\;\Bbb F_p[t]\;$ of which $\;\Bbb F_p(t)\;$ is the fraction field.

Now, you forgot that in characteristic $\;p>0\;$ the Freshman's dream is true: $\;(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p\;$ , so in your case

$$x^p-t=(x-t^{1/p})^p\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;t^{1/p}\in\overline{\Bbb F_p} =\;\text{some alg. closure of}\;\;\Bbb F_p$$

For (4): **why** is that the *minimal* pol. of $\;\sqrt2+\sqrt3\;$ ? Some explanation...?

The last part is nice and correct, imo.

Comment: **2)** I know that a polynomial of the form $x^{p-1}+...+1$ with $p$ prime is irreducible.  **3)** therefore $$E=\mathbb Q(t^{\frac{1}{p}})\cong \mathbb F_p(t)[X]/(X^p-t)$$ and thus $[E:\mathbb F_p(t)]=p$. Is the justification correct ? **4)** It has been proved in a previous exercise.

Comment: (3) It looks fine, but be careful: don't mix between $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and $\;\Bbb F_p\;$